# What algorithms could be used for the matching/pairing of word lists?

Tags: c#, algorithm, pattern-matching, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm working on some C# code to automate mapping of audio to text using the Google Speech-to-Text API for a language-study tool. I have a list of words parsed from the human-written source (transcript), also with sentence break information. I have a list of words with time stamps from the call to the Google API, which doesn't have sentence break information. I wish to find the words that match in order, such that I can determine time stamps for the sentence starting and ending points.

Because this is for multiple languages (some 60+), and because the text uses many archaic words which the Google API doesn't yet understand (I'm hoping their new enhanced mode will come soon for non-English languages), as well as there being certain things rendered differently in speech, this needs to be kind of a fuzzy matching mechanism.

I actually don't need to match all the words. As long as each sentence has a fair number of matching words, I can probably use those words as anchors and then look for the longest silence gap in the audio and consider it a sentence break.  But I'm having trouble coming up with even this basic word matching algorithm.  I think that knowing the sentence breaks in the source text should help. One problem is that there may be words in later text following a sentence that match which can throw everything off. so I need the best in-order matches.

Could someone point me to some code or algorithm details?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest beta version of the Google Speech API, you should find the sentence breaks that you need. I am using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1. Below is a sample of what I get back: (I converted a few fields to be in the format that I want.)

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "text": "Welcome everyone to the township council meeting Monday, June 22nd 2020. This meeting is now called to order mayor James Belford a mantle. Can you please lead us in the salute to the flag?",
      "confidence": 0.95940184593200684,
      "wordCount": 34,
      "words": [
        {
          "word": "Welcome",
          "confidence": 0.0,
          "startTime": 2400,
          "endTime": 4400,
          "speakerTag": 0,
          "wordNum": 1
        },
        {
          "word": "everyone",
          "confidence": 0.0,
          "startTime": 4400,
          "endTime": 4600,
          "speakerTag": 0,
          "wordNum": 2
```

You can send via the API a list of your archaic words (and phrases) that you know it will have trouble with. It will use this list as hints to the recognition process and likely then do the matching up of the audio and text that you desire. See: [Speech Adaptation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation)

Comment: How are you getting the sentences?  From the periods in the "text" field? I'm not getting any periods with Spanish.  I'm using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1P1Beta1, however I'm using the C# .Net API.  Also,  I passed in words via the Speech Adaptation, but it made little difference.  You must be using the English enhanced mode. When I worked on this a few months ago, there was not enhanced mode for any language other than English.  Has that changed?

Comment: Yes I meant the periods. Prior to using the Beta version, I was not getting back any punctuation at all. So I assumed this was your situation. It's seems unnecessary to me to be considering searching for the longest silence gap in the audio in order to guess at sentence breaks when you already have punctuation. Google is likely already using the silence gaps itself in order to locate sentence endings and insert punctuation. I've only been working with English transcription so far but will be working with other languages.